# Parsing iis log using worker role azure

Tags: logging, azure, azure-table-storage, logparser, azure-diagnostics

on stand alone hosting environment.
we use "scheduled service + powershell + log parser" to export iis log records into target database, and get all the stats that business dept. loves.

However when it comes to Azure, I am not sure if that is the right practice anymore.

I see people are exporting iis logs into azure storage. However we dont want to download the log files then exporting them into database from another server or local machine

I am wondering if there is anyone have done one step further i.e. export iis logs into azure storage table (make it query-able) by a worker role?

if there is anyone have done that or know any available solutions please pass on a link.

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking to analyze IIS logs by reading from Azure Blob Storage first, transferring to Azure Table storage in some easy to read/query format through a worker role? Great if you can add more on this regard to make it clear.

I personally think If you write a worker role to process stored IIS logs, It would be a very costly to just run a worker role for this purpose and that's why this is not a standard practice. Most 3rd party tool download the logs from Azure blob storage (***wad-iis-failedreqlogfiles*** and **wad-iis-logfiles** containers) and analyze locally and it just cost little.

Here is an old command line sample to [Download and Parse IIS Logs from Windows Azure](http://visitmix.com/LabNotes/Downloading-and-Parsing-IIS-Logs-from-Windows-Azure) using **logparser** (*save to Azure Table Storage is not included*) so you sure can put this together in a worker role and then add little more code to save your logs to Azure Table storage.